# binding a specific context to an event handler: Understanding functional context, return statements and closures?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, closures, anonymous-function

I'm reading John Resig's "Secrets of the Javascript Ninja" and in it he talks about changing the context of an event handler. In it he has the following code. I have no idea WHY it works. *Very lost on this one.*

```
<body>
    <button id="test">Click Me!</button>

    <script>
      function bind(context,name){                                 //#1
        return function(){                                         //#1
          return context[name].apply(context,arguments);           //#1
        };                                                         //#1
      }                                                            //#1

      var button = {
        clicked: false,
        click: function(){
          this.clicked = true;
          alert('It has been clicked! The value of clicked is ' + clicked);
        }
      };

      var elem = document.getElementById("test");
      elem.addEventListener("click",bind(button,"click"),false);     //#2

    </script>

  </body>
```

Namely I don't understand the bind function itself, AND I don't understand why it needs to be couched in an anonymous function. Because if I remove the bind() function and try any of the following, I always get the error message 'clicked is undefined'. To me, any of them would work by assigning the 'this' parameter to the button object, thus giving access to its clicked property:

```
    elem.addEventListener("click",button.click.apply(button),false);
```

in this next case I'm talking about javascript's native 'bind' function

```
    elem.addEventListener("click",button.click.bind(button),false);
```

As far as I can see, the next statement would be what John Resig's bind() function returns

```
    elem.addEventListener("click",function() { button.click.apply(button, arguments)},false);
```

But wait, there are TWO return statements in John Resig's bind function. At this point I'm just guessing - what about this next one?

```
    elem.addEventListener("click",function() { return button.click.apply(button, arguments)},false);
```

None of the above statements work.

Secondly, why does the bind function have two return statements? In my mind, bind would work as follows:

```
function bind(context,name){ 
            return function(){ context[name].apply(context,arguments); }; 
          }
```

Thirdly, if I take John Resig's bind function and try to assign it to a variable, say variable ninja, like so:

```
var ninja = bind(button,"click");
ninja;
```

I would expect to see the function returned to me look like:

```
function(){ button["click"].apply(button,arguments);
```

because the value of context and name would be filled in via closures. but instead it looks like:

```
function(){ context[name].apply(context,arguments);
```

So...I'm hoping the underlying cause of my confusion regarding all of these questions stems from the same fundamental concept that I am missing. Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a lot of questions! I'll try to help you clarify this.

- `addEventListener` expects a function reference as the second parameter. When you pass it `button.click.apply(button)`, you are [calling `click`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) immediately, and passing the return value of the click function (`undefined` in the example) to `addEventListener`. That's why it doesn't work.
- `bind` on the other hand returns a function, so calling it to get an event listener function is is appropriate.
- Your example that uses the [native `bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) should work, as well as the one following it, that tries to simulate the native `bind`.

> If I remove the bind() function and try anything, I always get the error message 'clicked is undefined'.

That is because your `button.click` function is flawed. It accesses a variable `clicked` that is defined nowhere. Only if the function is unintentionally called with the global object for [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) (like `button.click.call(window)`), then `this.clicked = true` creates a global variable that can be accessed thereafter. Change the function to

```
    alert('It has been clicked! The value of clicked is ' + this.clicked);
//                                                          ^^^^^
```

and every of your approaches will work.

> But wait, there are TWO return statements in John Resig's bind function.

The inner `return` in Resig's example will be the final return from the event listener. So for example if you want to prevent the default on a click handler, you can make it `return false`. Without the inner `return`, the event listener would return `undefined` instead of forwarding what the proxied listener function returns. This is not necessary for your examples, but it is a valuable characteristic of the `bind` function when it's used for [partial application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application).

> I would expect to see the function returned to me look like

Lastly, regarding your closure confusion: a closure is a function that keeps references to stuff from outer scopes (basically all functions do that in js). *But* the references do not replace the function body code as you expect in your example with `button["click"]`. In the function returned by Resigs `bind`, `context[name]` means `button["click"]`, but the code is not actually replaced; `context` points to `button`, and `name` holds the string `"click"`.

Comment: OK, I'm not going to write another answer now :-)

Comment: If you think you can add something to my answer, feel free to edit it. I'm not sure I answered *everything*.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this explains both of your questions.

The bind function

```
function bind(context,name){
    return function(){
      return context[name].apply(context,arguments);
    };
}
```

would get resolved at the firing of the event where it will return `button.name(event)`. The way it is processed is through

The `addEventListener` would, when an event is fired, use `fn.apply(elm, arguments)` to execute your code for each listener it has registered. Expanding this:

```
((function(){return button['click'].apply(button, arguments);})).apply(elm, arguments)
```

The anonymous function is used to pass-through the original arguments for the fired event and to replace `elm` with `button` as the `this` reference within the `button.click` code.

The other lines of code would cause errors in that when using the `apply` function on a `function`, parameters cannot be specified/referenced. Another way of thinking of it is, at runtime, you are creating a temporary method of `elm` defined by your `function`. The `function` may have parameters defined, but using those parameters chained before the `apply` will execute the function before the `apply` with the current value/reference of the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Basically it works like this.

- Context is the object you want to call.
- Name is the function in the object you want to call.

context[name].apply(context,arguments)

means
return the function

```
function(){
 context.name(arguments)
}
```

It will trigger context.name(arguments) when you want it to trigger instead of immediately when the page loads.